# What is the Railo web context "http://azenv.net:80"?

Tags: railo

While debugging a timezone issue with Railo and Postgres, I opened up the Railo Server Administrator and happened to notice the "Web contexts" section at the bottom. I recognized all the entries except for one:
[image: My "Web contexts" lists an entry for 'azenv.net:80']
What is "http://azenv.net:80"? Is that something that comes with Railo, or is my server `<GULP />` hacked?

Comment: A whois lookup doesn't reveal much. Registered via namecheap.com with privacy protection.

Comment: More curious: that label/webroot/configuration file entry is still there, but the "URL" field is now blank.

Answer (score 1):

Your server isn't hacked. What it looks like is that the domain http://azenv.net/ is pointing to your server. It could be or someone has a redirect pointing to your IP on their machine.

Now when your Railo server started up, usually the web contexts are blank (until it gets some domains) Railo doesn't know what the URL is at all. It got hit and went to the default context (webapps/ROOT) and it now thinks that is the default in your listing.

Maybe nothing to worry about, apart from why that domain is pointing to your server.

Comment: That's OK, but http://azenv.net/ is a "Proxy Judge" that can return information about your internal network, such as what proxy application is being used (squid, apache) and the internal address of the computer using it. I don't know why these these Proxy Judges are allowed; they don't really check security and they might give hackers info that they want to know.